# what goes in the root package.json in a lerna monorepo

Tags: lerna

I am confused as to what goes in the root package.json in a lerna monorepo.

say all my subprojects use react, does react go here?

What about references to other local packages?

say I have a package `@cutting/devtools`.

if i put it in the root package.json, it is not symlinking it to the root node_modules.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cutting/devtools": "0.11.8",
```

And if I increase the local package version, it tries to find it in npm but when I run `lerna list`, it is in the list

I dont understand why.

Comment: I have this same question. I haven't seen any guidance in any of the docs or articles I've read. Just getting started but so for now, the only thing in there is `lerna` as a devDependency.